Caladiums losing leaves or not growing well
My Caladium collection was doing well until last year. This time something went wrong with few of them. I took a snapshot of them beside each other for comparison

As you can see from the picture, there are quite different results, though they all got same growing conditions:
1- Dappled shade, lots of light, mostly indirect light
2- Watered when soil is dry, two to three times a week, depending on summer temperature.
3- I used the same type of potting mix, coco/perlite for all of them.
4- Received the same fertilizer dosage,
5- I gradually stopped watering in fall, allowing them to go dormant. When leaves begin to yellow, I stop watering completely.
6- Due to limited space, I remove the corms from the soil for winter storage. The corms are cleaned and once roots dry out I cut them. They are normally planted in fresh soil in spring, around March to early April.
What you see in the picture:

The two at the bottom had exceptionally small leaves. They were bigger last year. The one on the left is the most affected, having at the moment two yellow leaves, barely noticeable in the picture. They later fell off completely leaving an empty pot. I could feel one corm under the surface but not the other one.

Some leaves are pale

Many leaf stalks are so tall that they break easily. This not just adds clutter to the garden, but affects plant growth as the leaves constantly break off.

Ironically, the two variegated ones in the middle row performed the best, though they lack much chlorophyll. However, the others performed poorly.


So what happened to these Caladiums?

Are you growing them outdoors in the summer?

Seems like root rot problem with light/excess brightness/heat issue, not sure though.

@kevinskio Yes, I grow them outdoors. I have done it for a few years already. Few of the specimens are four years old. Last year I realized the leaf stalks were growing too tall and decided to move them to a brighter location. Back then, I did not have any growth issue shown here.

My recomomendation was to grow them outside, so that won't work!

How can shade plants be happy if the sun is strong enough for the cactus nearby?

@YosefBaskin I put them here for the snapshot. Their actual location is less sunny. It has some dappled shade (some sunlight passes through the trees above) and for just few hours.
